# WPF does not detect multi-keyboard input in textbox when typing quickly

Tags: c#, wpf

```
// This is event.
private void TextBox_Main_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Detect Ctrl + V
    if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.V)
    {
        // Code...
    }
}
```

I create a TextBox in the .NET 6 WPF environment, write and execute the code as above, and then press Ctrl+V it works well.
However, if I press and release Ctrl+V very quickly, the code doesn't work.
Can you figure out the cause?

I tried several other C# functions, but it didn't work.

Comment: I solved this problem with the code below, but I still wonder why question code works the way it does.

`if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) && e.Key == Key.V || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.V) && e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)`